# Где разместить класс описывающий исключение?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Здравствуйте. Где в Ruby On Rails нужно размещать классы описывающие исключения?
Интересует в какой директории/файле. Возможно для кода классов описывающих исключения нужно создать отдельный файл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Погуглил, почитал, спросил у коллег.
Выяснилось, что расположение классов с описанием исключений не регламентировано. Если исключений не много, то их можно поместить в файл (с именем, например,`errors.rb`), а файл - в директорию `config/initializers`